# IE8 "Object doesn't support this property or method" with JQuery 1.7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

When the following code is executed in IE 8 the console displays the error "Object doesn't support this property or method" for line 4 character 4. This only happens with IE 8. I'm using jquery-1.7.1.min.js

[image]

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var states = ["NEW YORK",
                  "PUERTO RICO",
                  "ALABAMA",
                  "ALASKA",
                  "AMERICAN SAMOA",
                  "ARIZONA",
                  "ARKANSAS",
                  "CALIFORNIA",
                  "COLORADO",
                  "CONNECTICUT",
                  "DELAWARE",
                  "DISTRICT OF COLUMBIA",
                  "FEDERATED STATES OF MICRONESIA",
                  "FLORIDA",
                  "GEORGIA",
                  "GUAM",
                  "HAWAII",
                  "IDAHO",
                  "ILLINOIS",
                  "INDIANA",
                  "IOWA",
                  "KANSAS",
                  "KENTUCKY",
                  "LOUISIANA",
                  "MAINE",
                  "MARSHALL ISLANDS",
                  "MARYLAND",
                  "MASSACHUSETTS",
                  "MICHIGAN",
                  "MINNESOTA",
                  "MISSISSIPPI",
                  "MISSOURI",
                  "MONTANA",
                  "NEBRASKA",
                  "NEVADA",
                  "NEW HAMPSHIRE",
                  "NEW JERSEY",
                  "NEW MEXICO",
                  "NORTH CAROLINA",
                  "NORTH DAKOTA",
                  "NORTHERN MARIANA ISLANDS",
                  "OHIO",
                  "OKLAHOMA",
                  "OREGON",
                  "PALAU",
                  "PENNSYLVANIA",
                  "RHODE ISLAND",
                  "SOUTH CAROLINA",
                  "SOUTH DAKOTA",
                  "TENNESSEE",
                  "TEXAS",
                  "UTAH",
                  "VERMONT",
                  "VIRGIN ISLANDS, U.S.",
                  "VIRGINIA",
                  "WASHINGTON",
                  "WEST VIRGINIA",
                  "WISCONSIN",
                  "WYOMING"];
    var _events = "change focusout";

    $("[name='payToBankState'], [name='amount'], [name='customerType'], [name='usdEquivalent'], [name='currency']").live(_events, function(event) {
        if($("[name='customerType']").val() == "Person" && states.indexOf($("[name='payToBankState']").val()) < 0) {
                if($("[name='currency']").val() == "USD") {
                    if($("[name='amount']").val() > 15 ) {
                        $("[name='pfhTran']").attr('checked', true);
                        $("[name='pfhTran']").removeAttr('disabled');
                    }
                    else {
                        $("[name='pfhTran']").removeAttr('checked');
                        $("[name='pfhTran']").attr('disabled', true);
                    }
                }
                else if ($("[name='usdEquivalent']").val() > 15) {
                    $("[name='pfhTran']").attr('checked', true);
                    $("[name='pfhTran']").removeAttr('disabled');
                }
                else {
                    $("[name='pfhTran']").removeAttr('checked');
                    $("[name='pfhTran']").attr('disabled', true);
                }
        }
        else {
            $("[name='pfhTran']").removeAttr('checked');
            $("[name='pfhTran']").attr('disabled', true);
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Are you certain this is the code causing the error? Every call seems contained to jQuery. Is there any other JS to share? Maybe a fiddle?

Comment: yeah, we need to see the rest, problem is not in code shown

Comment: Also, have you tried changing ".attr('checked', true)" to ".prop('checked', true)"?

Comment: @SteveHynding I changed the code to show the whole script and the error is displayed in the "IF", before it gets to the checkbox.

Comment: FWIW, I am unable to duplicate the issue using IE11 in IE8 mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method "indexOf" is not part of IE8's array methods. You should be able to quickly remedy this with jQuery.inArray: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Change:

```
states.indexOf($("[name='payToBankState']").val()) < 0
```

To:

```
$.inArray($("[name='payToBankState']").val(), states) < 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. This fixed the problem.

One question though: Does this approach will still work if I use it in IE 11?

Comment: You're welcome and yes, so long as you're using jQuery version >= 1.2. It is indifferent to whichever browser you're using.